UFW: allow all but restrict only one port
I have an application running on port 1111.
Is there any way to set up UFW so that it allows anything, but if the port is 1111, then it allows access only from certain IP to this port? Any other ports should be allowed by default for incoming traffic.

Do you mean the "Ubuntu Firewall"? If so, please note that acronyms can be convenient, but they are less precise and informative than spelling things out. Perhaps use the term "Ubuntu Firewall" near the beginning of your question, and then refer to it as "UFW" in the remainder of the question? Also, I'd guess the Ubuntu Firewall is pretty well documented. So, what research have you done regarding this and what have you tried so far? We don't want to suggest you try something you've already attempted.

Try something like: sudo ufw allow from 10.0.0.46 proto tcp to any port 1111.

harrymc, it will indeed allow from ip 10.0.0.46 to port 1111. But is there any way to restrict this port for any other IP? Any other port should be allowed by default.

@music2myear, UFW is the "Uncomplicated Firewall", which while often included in Ubuntu releases is not specific to Ubuntu. its a simple interface used to configure and view IP tables. Note that the actual command is ufw so its the actual product name, not just a shorthand that is used colloquially.

Frank Thomas, exactly!

This would be done with ufw deny 1111. The two rules could be specified, I suppose the deny should be first. (Add to your comment @harrymc for me to be notified.)

Then even moreso, please spell that out more clearly in your question. We need to know the full name of the product you're working with and the OS you're running it on, at a minimum, as well as any other information relevant to understanding your setup so we can understand your problem.

Well, you can change the default incoming rule to be allowed. It will ensure that incoming on all ports are allowed.
You get the following default rule with UFW. You can check it with
sudo ufw status verbose
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), deny (routed)

If you want to allow all incoming, then modify default rule using the following command:
sudo ufw default allow incoming

It will allow incoming to all your ports from any IP address. Though it is not recommended to allow anything to all ports, but it's your choice. Just make sure you know what you are doing.
After that, you can add a rule to allow access to your port 1111 from your specific IP. (10.0.0.10 is a sample IP, replace it accordingly).
sudo ufw allow from 10.0.0.10 to any port 1111

Since our default incoming rule is allow, we will have to add deny rule for port 1111
sudo ufw deny 1111

Keep in mind that you run the deny rule only after adding the allow rule for your IP. If you will add the deny rule first, then your UFW will just read that rule for port 1111 and ignore your allow rule. So, entry sequence in UFW matters in this case.
